# Differentiating distributions over a product space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $X=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ , we consider distributions in $\mathscr{D}'(X)$ to generalize functions $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Considering partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)$ now :

For $\ T\in \mathscr{D}'(X)\ $ is it true that $\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x} T(\phi)= -T(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi)\quad $ like in the case of 'single variable' distributions ?

And if this is the case, what are the conditions that we should verify before applying such differentiation ?

Comment: This is the definition of partial derivatives for distributions.

Comment: Take a sequence of smooths functions such that $T=\lim_{n\to \infty} T_n$ in the sense of distributions. Then integrate by parts $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\Bbb{R}^2} \partial_xT_n(x,y)\phi(x,y)dxdy$.

Comment: Answers: for Q1 yes, for Q2 none. The definition given by Jochen is equivalent to the procedure given by reuns because this is the only way to extend differentiation from ordinary smooth functions to distributions, by continuity.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, yes, this is the right way to define this, you will generally want to use integration by parts in order to decide how such an operation should be defined.

The thing you should probably verify is that $\phi$ is of the appropriate class of functions - in particular, the integration by parts step assumes that the "other" term is zero:
$$
\int T' \phi dx =  T\phi \vert^\infty_{-\infty} - \int T \phi' dx = - \int T \phi' dx
$$

i.e. that $T\phi$ vanishes at $\pm\infty$ in some sense. For the most basic class of distributions, this is ensured by taking $\phi$ to be compactly supported (in addition to smoothness), but one can consider other classes of distributions that act on less restrictive function spaces (tempered distributions on Schwartz functions and compactly-supported distributions on smooth functions).

Comment: thank you, my concern was for any partial derivative, say $\partial^\alpha T$ where $\alpha= (\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ is the usual n-tuple.

Comment: ok let me ask you about the different classes you mentioned in your second paragraph, when do you actually decide to limit yourself, for example, from general distribution in $D'$ to just tempered ones in $S'$, will this depend on your problem and which one will work?

Comment: Yeah, partial derivatives will work the same way here - think about what would result after integration by parts to arrive at the definition. For your second question, yes, it just depends on the specific problem you are working with, and generally you can use this identity to decide (or remember) what properties the spaces must have.

Comment: E.g. if you want to define $\partial^\alpha T$ for a general distribution, you will need to restrict yourself to functions for which $\partial^\alpha \phi$ is defined and for which $\phi$ vanishes at $\infty$. If you impose more on $T$, you can get away with less on $\phi$, etc.